# Error while accessing variable of a JSON object

Tags: javascript, async-await

I call two APIs to get a random GIF from GIPHY. I want to call my `gif()` function two times. Therefore, I use the `promises` array. Right now I get an error when returning the object in the `gif()` function.

```
return {
  img: responseJSON.data[0].images.original.url,
  word: wordJSON.word
}
```

`img: responseJSON.data[0].images.original.url,`
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'images')`

The strange thing is, I can access all the other values which are stored in `responseJSON.data[0].images.original` for example `size`

Any suggestions?

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  const gifURL = 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=key&limit=1&rating=g';
  const wordURL = 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/randomword';
  let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'x-api-key': '' }
  }


  promises = [gif(gifURL), gif(gifURL)];

  async function gif(gifURL) {
    const word = await fetch(wordURL, options);
    const wordJSON = await word.json();
    const response = await fetch(gifURL+'&q='+wordJSON.word);
    const responseJSON = await response.json();
    return {
      img: responseJSON.data[0].images.original.url,
      word: wordJSON.word
    }
  }


  function renderResults() {
    const values = Promise.all(promises)
      .then((values) => {
        console.log(values);
        return res.render('home', {"values": values});
      })

  }

  renderResults();
  

  
})
```

Comment: i had a similar problem so i used `window.onload = function () { //code here }` in my case i would have some code execute faster then the other one and would give `XY is not defined`

Comment: Can you try console logging values before return. You might get some hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this to debug

What does your system show on this? We can't do it easily here because we don't have the API.

```js
function get() {

  const gifURL = 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=key&limit=1&rating=g';
  const wordURL = 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/randomword';
  let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': ''
    }
  }

  promises = [gif(gifURL), gif(gifURL)];

  async function gif(gifURL) {
    const word = await fetch(wordURL, options);
    const wordJSON = await word.json();
    console.log("wordJSON:", JSON.stringify(wordJSON, null, 2))

    const response = await fetch(gifURL + '&q=' + wordJSON.word);
    const responseJSON = await response.json();
    console.log("responseJSON:", JSON.stringify(responseJSON, null, 2))

    return {
      img: responseJSON.data[0].images.original.url,
      word: wordJSON.word
    }
  }


  function renderResults() {
    const values = Promise.all(promises)
      .then((values) => {
        console.log(values);
        // return res.render('home', {"values": values});
      })

  }

  renderResults();



}

get()
```

Comment: So the code was fine, it was an issue with the Ninja API. It returns a random word, but if GIPHY don`t find a gif with the related word, it doesnt return an actual image. Therefore, the images is undefined.

Comment: Could you post your comment as an answer?